# Addpage wxAuiNotebook with an object in a vector

Tags: wxwidgets, listctrl

I'm currently working on a C++ `wxWidgets`-based software designed to show some data extracted from `.txt` files. Since I want to create multiple tabs, I decided to use `wxAuinotebook` with `wxListCtrl`.

To create a new tab in `wxAuiNotebook`, I need an object and I want this object to be a `wxListCtrl`. My goal at the moment is: every time I load a file, the software extracts some data and creates a new tab in the `wxAuinotebook`. And to do that, I create a new object in a dynamic array (vector) to have a new `ListCtrl` object as a base for the new tab every time.

Here are the interesting parts of my code:

```
std::vector<wxListCtrl> *Listes;
int nbr_listes = 0; // with a variable to store how many ListCtrl I create
```

I declare a vector to contain every `ListCtrl` objects. And, after the file loading, I create a new `ListCtrl` object in the vector:

```
Listes->push_back((new wxListCtrl(AuiNotebook1, ID_LISTCTRL1, wxPoint(121,48),
                                  wxDefaultSize, 
                                  wxLC_LIST|wxTAB_TRAVERSAL|wxVSCROLL,
                                  wxDefaultValidator, _T("ID_LISTCTRL1"))));
// And I want to add a page to the auiNotebook
if (!AuiNotebook1->AddPage(&Listes->at(nbr_listes), 
                           OpenDialog->GetFilename(), 
                           true,
                           wxNullBitmap)) //ajout d'une page passée en focus
    {
        cout << "Echec de l'ajout de page! \n";
    }
```

But the compiler returns an error in `listCtrl.h`:

> \include\wx\msw\listctrl.h|446|error: 'wxListCtrl::wxListCtrl(const wxListCtrl&)' is private

How can I properly add a page to the `auiNotebook` with a `ListCtrl` inside? I tried some different ways like declaring the vector as a vector of pointers, but that failed, too.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is probably a small typo but it doesn't work because of this:

```
std::vector<wxListCtrl> *Listes;
```

you probably ment to do

```
std::vector<wxListCtrl*> Listes;
```

**EDIT:**
That is because everytime you try to add a wxListCtrl to your vector as a variable allocated on the stack and not on the heap it has to call the copy constructor (which is declared private) and thus it generates your error.

In addition (depending on your wxWidgets version) I would suggest to display your data with wxDataviewCtrl

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the declaration like your suggestion and modified a little the code and now, it compile.

Comment: No Problem, that's what stackoverflow is here for